# Starting a new row in CSS Grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to generate a specific layout using CSS grids.
The layout I want is something like this:
[image]

Entire page is split into 12 columns. The first row cell is spanning entire first row, the second row has 2 cells spanning 4 columns each. The third row has 3 cells, spanning 3 columns each. But as per my code, the 3 cells of the third row, start in the second row itself.

My code:

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 24px;
}

.item {
  padding: 24px;
}

.banner-img {
  grid-column: span 12;
}

.card {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.note {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item banner-img">Hello</div>
  <div class="item card">Hello</div>
  <div class="item card">Hello</div>
  <div class="item note">Note</div>
  <div class="item note">Note</div>
  <div class="item note">Note</div>
</div>
```

How do I specify that .note div should start in a new row.

Comment: Is this specific item or some kind of repeatable layout? If specific, you can use [grid-row-start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row-start). For example: `.note { grid-row-start: 3 }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you aren't specifying which row to go in, there's room for the first `.note` element in the second row, so it goes there. So just tell these elements which row to sit in, with `grid-row: 3` etc.

```css
      * {
        border: 1px solid;
      }
      .wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        gap: 24px;
      }
      .item{
        padding: 24px;
      }

      .banner-img{
        grid-column: span 12;
      }

      .card{
        grid-row: 2;
        grid-column: span 4;
      }

      .note{
        grid-row: 3;
        grid-column: span 3;
      }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item banner-img">Hello</div>
      <div class="item card">Hello</div>
      <div class="item card">Hello</div>
      <div class="item note">Note</div>
      <div class="item note">Note</div>
      <div class="item note">Note</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `grid-row: 3` to note should fix your issue

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 24px;
}

.item {
  padding: 24px;
}

.banner-img {
  grid-column: span 12;
}

.card {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.note {
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item banner-img">Hello</div>
  <div class="item card">Hello</div>
  <div class="item card">Hello</div>
  <div class="item note">Note</div>
  <div class="item note">Note</div>
  <div class="item note">Note</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

1 way would be to add a 3rd card item with span 4.
if you can't, you can give another span to the second card item which is the 3rd item in wrapper

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: 24px;
}

.item {
  padding: 24px;
}

.banner-img {
  grid-column: span 12;
}

.card {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: span 8;
}

.note {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item banner-img">Hello</div>
  <div class="item card">Card</div>
  <div class="item card">Card</div>
  <div class="item note">Note</div>
  <div class="item note">Note</div>
  <div class="item note">Note</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't give the required result.